# Time parameter is not working in oracle sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I hace sql query through this i want to calculate the records after `05:00:00 PM` and before
`05:00:00 PM`.Here i smy query but through this i am getting wrong results please any one check this if any logical error in this

```
Select trunc(gross_weight_date) date1,
count(*) before5 
from wbg.WBG_01_01
where to_char(gross_weight_date,'HH:MI:SS PM')>'05:00:00 PM'
and item_cod = 16
and trunc(gross_weight_date)='05-JAN-2012' 
group by trunc(gross_weight_date)
order by date1
```

Any help may apprecaited

Comment: possible duplicate of [Split date field into time and day Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11069328/split-date-field-into-time-and-day-oracle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `chars` to compare dates. That won't work properly.

---

Since you only want to compare after 05 PM, here's an easier solution:

```
Select trunc(gross_weight_date) date1,
count(*) before5 
from wbg.WBG_01_01
where to_number(to_char(gross_weight_date, 'HH24MISS')) > 150000
and item_cod = 16
and trunc(gross_weight_date)='05-JAN-2012' 
group by trunc(gross_weight_date)
order by date1
```

It passes the value of the date to a char ('171212') and then to a number (171212) and compares it to 150000.

Comment: How will be converted please elloborate

Comment: @user1397781 you may try now :)

Answer (score 3):

1. Don't use VARCHAR2 to compare dates because characters are not sorted in the same order as numbers ('12' comes before '5').
2. Dont compare apples to oranges (`trunc(gross_weight_date)` is a date while `'05-JAN-2012'` is a VARCHAR2).

When working with dates, you can use date functions and date arithmetics without resorting to conversion, for example :

```
Select trunc(gross_weight_date) date1, count(*) before5 
  from wbg.WBG_01_01
 where item_cod = 16
   and gross_weight_date > to_date('05-01-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + 17/24 
   and gross_weight_date < to_date('05-01-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY') + 1 
 group by trunc(gross_weight_date)
 order by date1
```

or

```
Select trunc(gross_weight_date) date1, count(*) before5 
  from wbg.WBG_01_01
 where item_cod = 16
   and gross_weight_date > to_date('05-01-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY') 
                           + numtodsinterval(17, 'HOUR') 
   and gross_weight_date < to_date('05-01-2012', 'DD-MM-YYYY')
                           + numtodsinterval(1, 'DAY')
 group by trunc(gross_weight_date)
 order by date1
```

Comment: Just wondering if there was any particular reason to add the intervals as opposed to using time in the mask: to_date('05-01-2012 17:00', 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI')?

Comment: @glenn: most likely the date component and the time component will be variables/parameters. In that case it makes sense to add them without using a TO_CHAR conversion. In the case of constants, I agree using the time mask is easier to read.